# lxc-create stuck at connecting to archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: linux, lxc, lxc-docker

I am new to LXC. I tried to create ubuntu container using the command

```
lxc-create -n onos -t ubuntu
```

The installation ran for some time and got stuck with below message

```
Installing Update
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com
```

I am behind corporate proxy. Apt-get update works fine in host. But when I try to create a ubuntu container I am having the above issue.

Did anyone faced similar issue. Please help.

Comment: can you report the output here? at least the last few lines

Answer (score 0):

You should use proxy before lxc-create:

```
export http_proxy="http://$pre$server:$port/"
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
export rsync_proxy=$http_proxy
export HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
export HTTPS_PROXY=$http_proxy
export FTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
export RSYNC_PROXY=$http_proxy
lxc-create -n onos -t ubuntu
```

Also you can setup the proxy for apt:

```
#cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/30proxy 
Acquire::http::proxy "http://proxy:4128";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://proxy:4128";
```

PS:

[bug lxc-create doesn't take advantage of the apt proxy](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxc/+bug/1081786)

[Here: lxc-create not working behind proxy](https://www.mail-archive.com/lxc-users@lists.linuxcontainers.org/msg01947.html) a solution was:

> There was no problem with apt but, I had issue using debootstrap. Had
>   to set up the proxy settings in /etc/wgetrc. All fine now.